# Using enums correctly C++

Tags: c++, enums, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to learn how to use enums correctly in C++, and I can barely understand how to handle them. I made a simple program that changes traffic lights using enums and bitwise operations:

```
    #include <iostream>

enum lights
{
    green = 1,
    yellow = 2,
    red = 4,
    control = 7
};

std::string change_light (std::string choice)
{
    lights light;
    int changed;

    if (choice == "yellow")
        light = yellow;

    else if (choice == "red")
        light = red;

    else if (choice == "green")
        light = green;

    changed = control & light;

    if (changed == red)
        return "red";

    else if (changed == yellow)
        return "yellow";

    else if (changed == green)
        return "green";
}

int main()
{   
    std::string choice = "";

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "What light do you want to turn on?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        std::cout << "Changed to " << change_light(choice) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do I improve that program while keeping the use of bitwise operations and enums? If you could show me how to improve it, it would greatly improve my understanding of how to use enums correctly.

Thanks :D

Comment: The function doesn't really do anything. It just returns the same string (if it is one of the colors, otherwise undefined behavior). - Why not try switching from one color to another?

Comment: `changed = control & light;` is the same as `changed = light;` in this situation. In fact, the function change_light just returns it's input. Your example is not very strong. It's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I made that function just to experiment with enums. I want to know how I can make it better while using enums. If there is a way to shorten it while using enums, please show me how. I really don't get the usage of enums.

Comment: How can you make something that **doesn't do anything** (in a poor way - no return on bad input) better? - Rather, try to write a function that changes lights (partly can be achieved through bitshifting).

Comment: That's what I tried to do... But I'm confused with this whole topic of enums. Could you make such a function like you said and explain to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The whole idea behind enums is, that you can define a set of constants that give the user and compiler some hints about how a variable is to be used.

Your example would make more sense, if the change_light function would take a lights argument like this:

```
std::string change_light (lights choice)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
    case red: return "red";
    case yellow: return "yellow";
    case green: return "green";
    }
}
```

That way the compiler knows, that the function takes only certain arguments and you don't get function calls like change_light("blue")

---

So you use enums to protect the rest of your code from wrong argument values. You can't directly read an enum from std::in, since it doesn't know anything about your enum. After reading, you should convert the input to an enum. Something like this:

```
lights string_to_ligths(std::string choice)
{
    if(choice == "red") return red;
    if(choice == "yellow") return yellow;
    if(choice == "green") return green;
}
```

From here on all your traffic light related functions accept only enum values and don't need to check if the request value is within a valid range.

Comment: I tried that, but in the while loop inside main(), I call change_light() and pass a string to it(choice). I tried using cin to extract input to a lights variable, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That just brings me back to what I originally did. Probably means that I'm not using enums correctly. So could anyone show me how and when to actually use them? I'm really confused here.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are just integers that have a limited valid value ranges.

Lets say you would implement your semaphore with an int:

```
#define SEMAPHORE_STATE_RED 1
#define SEMAPHORE_STATE_YELLOW 2
#define SEMAPHORE_STATE_GREEN 3
int semaphore_state;
```

The following will pass just fine, although it breaks the semantics of your semaphore:

```
semaphore_state = 10;
```

with an enum it won't pass, compiler with catch the error.

This is even greater if you will use switch instead of if/else:

```
switch (state)
{
    case SEMAPHORE_STATE_GREEN: /* bla */ break;
    case SEMAPHORE_STATE_RED: /* bla */ break;
    /* if state would be enum, compiler would catch that we are missing the SEMAPHORE_STATE_YELLOW case */
}
```

Of course there are other uses of enums. For example I personally prefer enum constants over define (never actually using the enum type itself). This case is also the only one that can coexist with bitwise operations with much hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have the idea that the numbers associated with the enumerated type are important. In fact the numbers are not important at all. The real idea of the enumerated type is to capture, neatly, a variable that has a set of states which are *not* numerical and would also be poorly captured by using a character (e.g. playing-card suits, compass directions or days of the week). One would seldom, if ever, assign a specific numbers to any of the enum values - it is a facility that is not part of the point of the enumerated type (but it is very occasionally useful so it is kept) and serves more to confuse the beginning programmer than to assist, and should not be envisaged as an integral part of enumeration - some languages do not even permit it (e.g. Modula-3, Haskell, Ocaml). Enumerated types are not very often used - their use is a bit obscure and they are not often useful: they add clarity to a program but not power (contrast with, for example the **if** statement without which programming would be nigh impossible!) and are never actually *needed* as such. This means that the fragment of code that you wrote, while it shows an enumerated type in use, does not demonstrate its usefulness: an enumerated type comes into its own in clarifying an aspect of some larger programs, a use not easily demonstrated. Beginning programmers are best advised to ignore them as they seem pointless and confusing to the beginner. This is because their purpose is hard to demonstrate - though they are useful, I promise you! I repeat: they offer clarity of expression, not power.

Comment: Enums are extremely commonly used as named bit-flags, so in that case the numerical value is of utmost importance.